# I need clarification in php date function

Tags: php

I am generating next date using the following code:

```
   $s1=date('d/M/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
   echo $s1;
```

for ex: Assume current date is 26/Aug/2014.
        so above code generates 27/Aug /2014 and storing in varible $s1.

By using the varible s1 i want to create 28/Aug/2014. how to create?

I dont want to use '+2 day' in STRTOTIME function. I want to generate next day based on variable $s1.

Comment: please, read php documentation for date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Reading docs has never hurt anyone 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `date('d/M/Y', strtotime($s1 . ' +1 day'))`

Comment: @h2ooooooo That generated `01/Jan/1970`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all with `strtotime()` but you have to remember that `strtotime` assumes a USA date format when it see's a `/` forward slash as a seperator.
So before using $s1 you need to convert the `/` to a `-` so it assumes a sensible data format is being used.

```
$s1=date('d/M/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
echo $s1.PHP_EOL;
// change date format as strtotime assumes USA dates
$date = strtotime( '+1 day', strtotime( str_replace('/','-',$s1) ) );
echo date('d/M/Y', $date);
```

When run on 26/Aug/2014 the result would be

```
27/Aug/2014
28/Aug/2014
```

Comment: Look at the code I just posted, the `str_replace()` does the format amendment.

Comment: Okay Thanls a lot Riggs Folly. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way (using `strtotime`):

```
$tomorrow     = strtotime('+1 day');
$twoDaysHence = strtotime('+1 day', $tomorrow);

echo date('d/M/Y', $tomorrow);
echo date('d/M/Y', $twoDaysHence);
```

In other words, leave your date variables in the form of UNIX timestamps as returned by `strtotime` until you need to *display* them. Because you can do calculations directly with them in this format. Once you format that to a date string, you'll have to convert them back into a malleable form first. `strtotime` doesn't recognise the format `d/M/Y` automatically, so that makes that all the harder. You should use `DateTime` in that case:

```
$tomorrow  = date('d/M/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $tomorrow);
$timestamp->modify('+1 day');
echo $timestamp->format('d/M/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s1=date('d/M/Y', strtotime('+1 day'));
echo $s1; echo "<br/>";
$date = strtotime(strtotime($s1). ' + 2 days');
$s2 = date('d/M/Y', $date);
echo $s2;
```

Now it's edited!! Check it!

Comment: Actually, it generates `1970-01-02`, but that's close enough, right?

Comment: i tried your code in php oline editor and i am getting this result 02/Jan/1970.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following:

```
$newvariable = strtotime ('+2 day' , $s1);
```

Comment: Actually, it generates `1970-01-02`, but that's close enough, right?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very simple part

$s1=date('d/M/Y', strtotime('+2 day'));

echo $s1;

and if you want then copy the value of $s1  in another variable

Comment: as OP said 2nd date to be generated from first one not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

```
function date_addDate($text, $da=0, $ma=0, $ya=0, $ha=0)
{
    $h=date('H',strtotime($text));
    $d=date('d',strtotime($text));
    $m=date('m',strtotime($text));
    $y=date('Y',strtotime($text));
    $fromTime =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($h+$ha, 0, 0, $m+$ma, $d+$da, $y+$ya));
    return $fromTime;
}

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// $da days
// $ma months
// $ya years
// $ha hours
echo date_addDate($date, $da=0, $ma=0, $ya=0, $ha=0);
```

//out put : current date

```
echo date_addDate($date, $da=2, $ma=0, $ya=0, $ha=0);
```

//out put : As you want 
Try this

Answer (score 0):

What about using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) ?

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$d1->format('d/m/Y'); // 26/08/2014
$d1->modify('+1 day');
$d1->format('d/m/Y'); // 27/08/2014
```